# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderators

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase *(activated only if there are more than 10 nominees)*
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

#### https://stackoverflow.com/election

for more details, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for the candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: So what goes into the answer box?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Nothing usually. Sometimes people try to close these questions and when they do a mod comes in and it becomes a battle.

Comment: Battling with mods is... not a winning strategy.

Comment: @CodyGray - So long as it doesn't come from above.

Comment: Given that there is a defined way to ask questions to candidates in this question, is there a reason people can comment on candidates when they nominate?

Comment: @nvoigt You mean that the general questions in the questionnaire should be the end of our ability to ask questions of candidates? I'm not sure I agree with that. Specific questions might be asked of specific candidates, under their nomination. Or did you mean that questions can be asked *here*? That's not really the intention. Although I'm not quite sure *what* the intention of this particular Meta Q&A is, other than an announcement.

Comment: @CodyGray No, I mean since *this* question states we should open meta questions with the tag [election] to ask potential moderators questions, there is no need to have comments on the candidates to ask questions, too. We don't need *two* approaches how we ask specific candidates specific questions, right? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @nvoigt Oh, I think it means that you should ask new questions on Meta if you have *general* question about the election, such as about the election process, how to nominate, etc. Asking new questions on Meta isn't really a great way of asking questions of the candidates. There's no guarantee that they'll see them or answer them. It wouldn't really be any different than starting a Meta discussion at any other time, and just reading the opinions of the folks who choose to weigh in.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, okay, then you may want to remove the part where it says ", or questions for moderator candidates", it's easy to misunderstand and could just be removed.

Comment: @nvoigt That is.. a good point. I confess that I must have never read this closely enough to have noticed that. It is curious that that phrase is included. And it looks like it has been included for many years. I don't know if it is advice that is past its time and needs to be removed, or if it's actually something we've been overlooking all these years, and, as you said, it would be better to ask questions of candidates here on Meta (where such discussion can be more easily moderated) than under the nominations themselves. I'll have to think about it!

Comment: The comments are locked during the Primary and Election phases of the election, so it may be a reference to that period of time as well.

Comment: Where can I find information about how many moderators you plan to recruit? It used to be 3 before "pronoun-gate". Last year it was 2. This year...?

Comment: @Lundin - it says "positions 2" at the top of [the election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTy65.png).

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thanks! That was sneakily hidden (these columns get printed with far more space in between than on your screenshot on my large PC monitor).

Comment: Hey @CodyGray, this shouldn't be closed, should it?

Comment: @user17242583 Thanks for the question/alert. However, I don't see the harm in leaving this particular question closed. It wouldn't be appropriate to answer it anymore. I'm actually just going to lock it as obsolete. We definitely don't need to have people close-reopen warring over it.