# Can we ask questions for Moderator Candidates here on Meta?

Tags: support, moderator-election

On the [2021 Community Moderator Election Announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412176/2021-community-moderator-election) question it says:

> If you have ... questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Does this means that during the election we can ask questions directed at the candidates that they could chose to answer, in addition to the "official" questionnaire?

Personally, I think the idea could work, would help as to get additional feedback now that the comments on the election page are closed, and provide a way to interact with candidates in a more meaningful manner during the election.

But if were permissible, we should set some "ground rules" that we could collectively enforce to keep things reasonable.

For example:

- Questions should not be asked at a specific candidate, but should be answerable by any of the candidates.
- Non-candidates should not post answers to [election](/questions/tagged/election) questions.
- Deadline to post questions should be 24hs before the election ends, to give all candidates a chance to answer.

etc.

Comment: You say they shouldn't be directly at a specific candidate, but isn't it more likely that the questions *are* going to be at a specific one? I for example, would love to know why one candidate didn't take the time to complete the questionnaire yet still think we should vote for them.

Comment: I knew that particular example would come up, but I still believe the questions should be answerable by any candidate. So for a question like that, it should IMO be posted in such a way that any other candidate could chime in, if possible, or not at all. But that's just my opinion, I'm pretty much against about 1-on-1 Q&As for our format.

Comment: Honestly, if the comments weren't locked I am all but sure *at least* one person would have asked them why; but the fact they are (and i feel that it's an incredibly important question) means that (from my perspective) getting an answer to said question outweighs the suggestion of making them candidate agnostic.

Comment: I understand your position. Let's agree to disagree. I believe a question about that could be posted without being it directed exclusively at one particular candidate, and I still believe that this is not the right place to post questions to a single user.

Comment: True, I think I certainly could word such a question to be candidate agnostic, but I feel that such a question's true intent would be abundantly clear. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Feel free to post a Meta question aimed at a candidate. As long as you're not violating any rules and asking good-faith questions, that will be fine. Politics Meta [has a decent rundown of what a good-faith question looks like](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3040), if you need some general guidelines. Mods do try to keep things as fair as possible while allowing discussion, and we will remove anything we see as purely trying to skew the view of a candidate.

The catch here is there's no innate mechanism to notify a candidate that they have a question aimed at them. Most of the candidates tend to hang out in the election chat room (a link to the current chat room is on the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) when an election is running), so you can probably ping them there and link to your question. But there's no requirement for any candidate to join the room, and they may not be pingable there. If a candidate does not want to participate in any way outside of the normal election processes, we don't really have any mechanisms to make them do so.