# Why are comments disabled in elections once the election phase starts?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

In the current election a candidate nominated themselves shortly before the end of the nomination phase. This has meant that no discussion of the candidate happened as the nomination phase ended and then comments were locked.

The other 5 nominees all had significant discussion, both good and bad, about them. This doesn't seem particularly fair and seems like a good way for someone with an otherwise great nomination to hide a particular issue.

I agree that ultimately your votes SHOULD be your votes but I think it's naive to expect humans to not weigh in others opinions as they make their own.

Furthermore, expecting users with 150 rep (the requirement to vote) to have intimate knowledge of who is who is unrealistic. These people, myself included, can make a decent assessment from the election score and the Q/A. However, as the Q/A is from the nominee themselves it is helpful to have the discussion in the comments and see how other users, especially higher rep users, feel about them.

Should there be a waiting period between nominations closing and the election starting to allow time for discussion?

Alternatively, why even lock comments during the election?

Comment: ...and could they also not be hidden? (they're on the nomination tab, with no indication to look there)

Comment: You can go back to the nomination phase to see them but that is annoying https://stackoverflow.com/election/13?tab=nomination

Comment: @RyanM for clarity (and I know what you mean) - they are visible by going to the Nominations tab. However, not when looking at the Elections tab. And the latter is what a user goes in order to vote, it's not obvious that there is extra information elsewhere.

Comment: @SamDean that's still *hidden*, in my book.

Comment: I think Monday should be the comment day and the election should last 7 days.

Comment: The thing is that comments suck quite a bit for this. Not only they are hidden, but the long threads are not particularly friendly. So I agree, if we use comments there is no reason to close them 7 days before the end of the election, but in the end a better tool would be better for this. (See my [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412361/1426539), if you want).

Comment: Would there be any point in having a 24 hour 'grace period' between the end of nominations and start of either the primary or the election during which comments could be made and questions could be asked?  Would that resolve the problem more simply?

Comment: How about we have a commenting phase in the middle then? That way all nominees get the same amount of time for folk to pose questions and make points. The lack of a meta post this year is particularly frustrating for me because I don't have a place to do that now, or see other people making comments that I was unaware of. I have no idea who to vote for now.

Comment: "why even lock comments during the election" - to avoid people potentially bringing things up in the middle of an election and having a lot of people vote based on that information before the nominee can defend themselves (or before it can be deleted, if it violates commenting guidelines), and having a lot of people who already voted, who didn't get to see that.

Comment: @NotThatGuy locking the comments has enabled that exact thing to happen. One nominee was accused of a bunch of stuff with no proof. The nominee that signed up last minute had none of that. So now if people look at the comments and see bad things for one and nothing for the other that could well unfairly swing their vote

Comment: @SamDean That's a different problem from what I'm talking about. You can fix your problem without causing my problem by instead adding a period of time where neither new nominations nor voting is possible and only commenting is allowed. "One nominee was accused of a bunch of stuff with no proof" - in its current state, the only accusations I see are addressed by the nominee (and they don't deny it, so it's probably accurate enough). 1/2

Comment: ... It's true that we don't know the specifics of the accusations based on those comments, but that's not the issue being discussed here. Note that a mod removed a few comments that crossed the line, which demonstrates my point: you'll have people who voted based on those comments if they happened during voting. 2/2

Answer (score 64):

#### Don't lock the comments on nomination posts during the election phase

Previously, we had the Meta questionnaires as a place to ask additional questions of candidates during the election phase.  This ensured that any candidate who filled out the questionnaire had a chance to have potential concerns raised (or positive things said).

With the integrated questionnaire (which is great, and otherwise *much* better!), that's no longer available.  Thus, it makes sense to leave the discussions open.

As part of this, it would make sense to have the discussions available on the election tab ([related MSE feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234118/165261)), so that the discussion is visible to voters who didn't visit the page during the nomination phase.

Comment: Another, more recent related MSE feature request (shameless plug): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370962/implement-a-waiting-period-between-the-close-of-nominations-and-the-voting-sta

Comment: That being said, this answer is worded like a response to a feature request, but doesn't make a ton of sense as a response to a discussion question, at least as currently worded.

Comment: @TylerH Fair, but it felt duplicative to post as a standalone FR given how similar it is to this.

Comment: Perhaps edit the [tag:feature-request] icon into the answer to make it clear that's what you're doing?