# What's the point of the nomination phase Q&A if it's hidden now?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderator-election

Why are the comments under a candidate's nomination hidden?

I would wager a vast majority of voters haven't been keeping track of the nomination phase and the comments under each nomination.
Now that all those comments are hidden, we can no longer see how a candidate deals with criticism (or doesn't), nor can we see users vouching for a candidate's "moderation"  experience.
("moderation" as in community-based cleanup efforts like SOCVR, SOBotics, and burninations)

Sure, comments are not meant to be significant on SO itself, but I think they provide unique, and often critical insight into a candidate's personality and suitability for a position as moderator.

Comment: The comments are still available by navigating to the _Nomination_ tab, but I agree that those comments could just be reachable on all tabs for clarity.

Comment: Related on MSE (2014): [Comments on moderator nomination statements should be more visible in all stages of the election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222078/241919)

Comment: It isn't about clarity, in my opinion. Not everyone knows comments are only visible on the nomination, and consequently don't know that they should look there. Hiding it is effectively the same as making it non-existent for most users

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! I completely forgot/missed/never realized there's a nomination tab o.O

Comment: On the bright side, fantastic demonstration of why the current system is problematic :')

Comment: Probably also worth looking into the design of the tabs. If people don't recognise them as clickable tabs, but rather some weird progress bar, that's a problem

Comment: Well, the 3 Tabs (Bar) should be displayed at the very Top of each Page, and not after scrolling down for 3 full Screens... // "Funny" btw that the 6 Candidates are sorted randomly on the `Election` + `Primary` Tabs but (still) in the "original" (Reverse) Order on the `Nomination` Tab... // And the `Primary` Tab even "offers" Up+Downvote Buttons for all Candidates... (Semi-Disabled, but still a bit weird...)

Comment: Related from last year: [Why are comments disabled in elections once the election phase starts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412363/8967612) See: [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/873997) and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412368/8967612).

Comment: Yeah I find it annoying that someone nominated themselves a few hours before nominations closed, so there could be hardly any Q&A from the community (in different timezones) nor that it could be read when there was any. Edit: I could swear I clicked the Nomination tab and there were no comments there shortly after the election phase began.

Comment: @CodeCaster Huh? We didn't get a last-minute nomination this time...

Comment: @Cerbrus sideshowbarker nominated themselves eight hours before nominations closed, IIRC. I only saw theirs when the election phase started. Haven't had time to discuss with them, but I see you did, so that's nice.

Comment: I guess that's timezones then. I didn't realize it was that close.

Comment: "Burnination" is so...  2010's.

Comment: There is definitely a usability problem. Before reading ***the comments*** to this meta post, I also thought the comments from the nomination phase were removed/deleted. (I would have read [the 24 comments](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14?tab=nomination#comment131392953_74429388) to 
sideshowbarker's nomination.)