# How many visits were made to the election page?

Tags: support, moderator-election, statistics, views

There are 2 links with the same name *(2021 Community Moderator Election)* displayed on the sidebar for the election:

[image]

The first one brings us to the election page, while the second one brings us to the meta post for the election. Currently the [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412176/13552470) only has 2500 views, which *(in my eyes)* is very low for something so big. **Is there any way to see how many views/visits were made to the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election)?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure what the logic is here, but only mods get the full blue box right above the candidates' statements (for everyone else it says "Election closes in X days."). Once the election ends, everyone gets the blue box (visible on [the 2020 election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12)).

At present there's just over 64k views.

Answer (score 7):

While the information on the election page is (at the moment) not visible to regular users,<sup>1</sup> anybody can see at least the number of [Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus) and [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badges. And one can compare this with the numbers before elections. Either manually (probably only on smaller sites) or using SEDE. Here is a query for number of [Caucus](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1316191/number-of-badges-of-a-certain-kind-within-the-given-date-range?name=Caucus&Date2=2021-01-01) and [Constituent](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1316191/number-of-badges-of-a-certain-kind-within-the-given-date-range?name=Constituent&Date2=2021-01-01) badges until a certain date.

At the moment, the SEDE queries return 747,506 and 247,589. (That is the status before the election.) Checking the numbers on the site gives 820,984 and 271,848. That means that [73,478 Caucus badges](https://www.google.com/search?q=820984-747506) and [24,259 Constituent badges](https://www.google.com/search?q=271848-247589) have been awarded (so far) for this election.

---

<sup>1</sup>See also: [Why are election statistics only shown to moderators during the nomination phase?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371113) and [Make the mod-only-status of election turnout obvious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307153) on Meta Stack Exchange.